# htaccess resulting in 500 internal error on adding @ or space in rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am having problem in my htaccess rewrite rule i.e when i add space or @ symbol for not giving 404 error page for profile page's which contain space in between them eg: www.domain.com/rahul kapoor or www.domain.com/rahul@gmail.com it gives 500 internal error.
my .htaccess is :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-@ ]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the rule's regex if you want to use spaces. Also important is to use `NE` flag for not encoding.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^([-a-zA-Z0-9._@ ]+)/?$" profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

You can use `\w` for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so 2nd rule will become:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^([\w.@ -]+)/?$" profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: yeah, it's now not giving 500 error and showing profile page but it's only showing page without showing any name and furthur info from database any idea why this happens ?

Comment: ok see updated answer with `NE` flag. btw what is the original URL you're opening?

Comment: it's still not working , you can see it here http://www.hootpile.com/Shyam%20Padhi

Comment: Well that is because of your code in `profile.php`. This rule is working fine. Make sure to access GET parameter using `$_GET["u"]`

Comment: i am using the same , any other suggestion ?

Comment: If you print it using `var_dump($_GET['u'];` what do you get?